# Why terraform plan or terraform apply uses different workspace than it should use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I added two terraform workspaces. (Terraform v0.14.6)
In my folder I have three files with .tfvars extension:

```
terraform.tfvars
abc.tfvars
123.tfvars
```

When I run terraform workspace list I see three workspaces and workspace abc is marked *

```
default
*abc
123
```

The problem is that, If I run terraform plan or terraform apply, terraform uses settings from workspace default and settings from terraform.tfvars not from abc.tfvars

I have a question: Do you want to perform these actions in workspace abc? But after this terraform doesn't uses abc.tfvars but terraform.tfvars. Why?

terraform.tfvars

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxx"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxx"
LinkedAccount = "9xxxx"
```

abc.tfvars

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxx"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "xxxx"
LinkedAccount = "8xxxx"
```

If it is difficult to say why, I can put here my main.tf, variables.tf files as well. Maybe it is simple issue to resolve and someone sees where it is my mistake. Let me know.

Comment: "settings from workspace default": what do you mean by this? "terraform.tfvars not from abc.tfvars": `terraform.tfvars` is an auto-loaded variable input file. If you want dynamic inputs, these should be controlled within the module declaration, environment, and/or other standard methods of providing inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tell Terraform which variable file to load via the `-var-file` switch like this:

```
terraform plan -var-file=abc.tfvars
```

Terraform Documentation: [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files)

It's also worth reading this GitHub issue: [Feature: Conditionally load tfvars/tf file based on Workspace #15966](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15966)